# camel: unmarshaling non-json data

Tags: apache-camel

I have data coming in from an external server into my route in these two forms:

```
1) []
2)["123", "234", "345"]
```

The data as you notice is not a json data, but an array of Strings representing Integer data type. I need to get out of it an Array of Integers. I was attempting to use unmarshal mechanize, but to no good luck since unmarshal appears to work only on json data from what I can tell. I hope someone can recommend something already in camel that I could utilize. Any help is much appreciated... 
I do have a workaround for it - getting it as String, then striping [,],". But I'd like to find a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

See the message translator eip: http://camel.apache.org/message-translator.html

You can use a java bean to do the transformation which is a clean solution. Or you can also implement a custom data format if you want to use unmarshal.